# Replace a div with another div in ajax/javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<div class="col" style="border-right:none; color: #FFFFFF;">
    <form id="form-search" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <span>
            <span class="style2">Enter you email here</span>:
        </span>
        <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>
        <input type="submit" value="subscribe" class="submit" style="height:30px;"/>
    <?php
            if($_POST['email']!="")
            {
                mysql_connect("localhost","","");
                mysql_select_db("");
                error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);
                $email=$_POST['email'];
                $sql="INSERT INTO newsletter_email(email) VALUES ('$email')";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                if($result){
                    echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
                }
                if(!$sql)
                    die(mysql_error());
                mysql_close();
            }
        ?>

    </form>
</div>
```

After the user got subscribed, I want to replace my subscription form and display the echo statement.

This code is running totally fine and is very good too; just want some more advantage with it.. ..

it shows like this[image]

But i want to show it like this    [image]

> my code now

```
<div class="col" style="border-right:none; color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <script>
                     var form = $('#form1');
   $.ajax{
         type:form.attr('method'),
         url:form.attr('action'),
 data:$("#form1").serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    if(data=="You have been successfully subscribed."){
                     $(".col").html("<div>Welcome</div>")

    }

    }
                    </script>

<form id="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
<span><span class="style2">Enter you email here</span>:</span>
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>
<input type="submit" value="subscribe" class="submit" style="height:30px;"/>
            <?php
if($_POST['email']!="")
{
mysql_connect("localhost","","");
mysql_select_db("");
error_reporting(E_ALL && ~E_NOTICE);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO newsletter_email(email) VALUES ('$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
    echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
}
 if(!$sql)
die(mysql_error());
mysql_close();
}
?>

</form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ajax is used as agent between html and php, The details entered in html form is supplied to php through ajax and the result obtained from php is sent back through ajax.This can be done by php itself, but the use of ajax create a non-flickering page i.e a portion of webpage is updated without a full request.

```
   var form = $('#form1');
       $.ajax{
             type:form.attr('method'),
             url:form.attr('action'),
     data:$("#form1").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        if(data=="You have been successfully subscribed."){
                         $(".col").html("<div>Welcome</div>")

        }

        }
```

HTML code:

```
       <HTML>
       <BODY>
       <div class="col">
           <form id="form1" action="index.php" method="POST">
              <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required/>
              <input type="submit" value="subscribe" class="submit" style="height:30px;"/>
          </form>
       </div>
       </body>
        </html>
```

Update ajax code

```
   var form = $('#form1');
       $.ajax{
             type:form.attr('method'),
             url:form.attr('action'),
     data:$("#form1").serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        if(data=="You have been successfully subscribed."){
                         $(".col").html("<div>Welcome</div>")
                     }    
       },
             error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
              }
       }
```

Comment: hey wat u ve described, this is what i want, but ur code dint work

Comment: what is inside the echo "Success" should be same inside if(data=="Success"), otherwise it will not work

Comment: Even if it does not works check your browser console to see for jquery error or show me your code

Comment: i ve updated my question with the code i m using(given by u) .. see it @cy5

Comment: the script should always be at the bottom of the body

Comment: Have you check that Insertion is successfull, if its not then echo it and create else condition in ajax and print out to html "error in insertion

Comment: everythng is running fine

Comment: if its problem in ajax then you can see the error,just after success:
function(data){},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
or
instead of $(".col").html("<div>Welcome</div>") use $(".col").hide()

Comment: if you don't understand the above comment, i have update the ajax code

Comment: @CY5 Your code won't work, for the simple reason that `index.php` does not contain the single line of content that you've specified.

Comment: yeah right i just gave an example "index.php" i thought OP must have modified it. Thanks @Daedalus

Comment: @sarmistha have you seen Daedalus comment you should remove action="index.php" and put your php file name.

Comment: Got a link, Simple Ajax Login form with Jquery and PHP. Try this might help http://www.ondeweb.in/ajax-login-form-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

after you submit the ajax you can simply hide the email input and button

```
$("#email").hide();
```

==========================================

```
<form id="form-search" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

then somewhere in your page

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
$("#email").hide();
$(".style2").hide();
$(".submit").hide();

return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: or you can add onsubmit to your form and put a JS function to hide it

Comment: assuming you have jquery, and it's a really bad example, since it hides whether it's successful or not

Comment: You have to hide whole form `$('#form-search').hide()`, instead hide each elements of this form

Comment: try now, i didn't type return true

Answer (score 0):

edit your php code like this;

```
if($result){
    <script>
      $(".class").hide(); // get input class name
    </script>
    echo "You have been successfully subscribed.";
}
```

Comment: but we cant use a script in php in that if statement na ??